# How to set CS pin on Beetle BLE/Bluno Beetle to Adafruit SD Card Breakout - Initialization Failed!

Tags: arduino-uno, sd-card, adafruit

Hi I have a Beetle BLE (https://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/Bluno_Beetle_SKU:DFR0339) and I am trying to connect an Adafruit MicroSD card breakout board+ (https://www.adafruit.com/product/254) via SPI connections. I am trying the following code, but I am having trouble selecting the CS pin using D4 since the Beetle has no D10. Does anyone know if I am selecting D4 correctly, while keeping pin 10 as an output. I keep getting initialization failed! My setup is on the ICSP 6 pin configuration:

5V --> 5V

MISO --> DO

SCK -->CLK

GND --> GND

MOSI --> DI

D4 --> CS

RST is left out

Here is my code:

```
#include <SPI.h>

#include <SD.h>

File myFile;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
  // On the Ethernet Shield, CS is pin 4. It's set as an output by default.
  // Note that even if it's not used as the CS pin, the hardware SS pin 
  // (10 on most Arduino boards, 53 on the Mega) must be left as an output 
  // or the SD library functions will not work. 
//   pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
//   digitalWrite(4, HIGH); // Add this line

  if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");

  // open the file. note that only one file can be open at a time,
  // so you have to close this one before opening another.

  myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);

  // if the file opened okay, write to it:
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.print("Writing to test.txt...");
    myFile.println("testing 1, 2, 3.");
  // close the file:
    myFile.close();
    Serial.println("done.");
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  // nothing happens after setup
}
```

Comment: Schematic of the Bluno beetle can be found here: https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1259.html The atmega is connected with rx and tx via 4k7 resistor to the bluetooth chip and the bluetooth chip is connected to usb. The spi bus is not used on the module, so there is no problem with other chips. Setting pin 10 as output and use pin 4 as chip select should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct ICSP was on the right, ICSP1. However, the orientation of those pins were from left to right on the TOP: SCK, 5V, MISO; left to right on the BOTTOM: MOSI, RESET, GND. In the Wiki they had the ICSP labels 1 and 2 reversed, but correct in the text below. https://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/Bluno_Beetle_SKU:DFR0339

Therefore, there was nothing wrong with the code, only the wiring to the correct pins!

Answer (score 1):

The ICSP header **labels on the Wiki page are wrong**. In the schematic [here](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1259.html) the ICSP header has the same pinout as other Arduinos. The legend doesn't match the picture on the Wiki page but is true:

- ICSP1: Atmega 328P
- ICSP2: CC2540

The ICSP header is the inner one. Is right on the pictures.
At pin 1 on board the corner of the white square around pins is skewed. The pins are from left to right first row Eeset, CLK, MISO, second row Ground, MOSI, 5 V.

[pdf schematic for the board](https://github.com/Arduinolibrary/DFRobot_Bluno_Bettle/blob/master/DFR0339-Bluno%20beetle%20V1.0.pdf?raw=true)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Juraj, thanks for your reply. There are many links on that page link including the one I sent you. Could you please send a direct link to the correct ICSP diagram? Appreciate it.

Comment: added to the answer

Comment: Juraj and @Jot how does that correspond to the pins on the board in this picture? I'm not sure how to tell: [ICSP Pin Pic](https://i.imgur.com/MQTGSIx.jpg)

Comment: one corner is marked. it is pin 1 MISO

Comment: Sorry Juraj, I don't see it. Can you be more specific as to the order and orientation?

Comment: I edited the answer

Comment: Hi @Juraj. I soldered the wires this evening, but I'm still getting "initialization failed".   For the pins, how did you figure out that the diagram on the Wiki page was incorrect to begin with? PS - the same setup works on my Arduino Pro Mini, but I definitely want to get it working on the Beetle for my project.

Comment: I connected AVR ICSP header with dupont jumper wires so many times that I know the pinout without a diagram. And an Atmega 328 board can't have a different pinout of ICSP header because the AVR programmer connector would not match.

Comment: I'm still getting initialization failed. Any ideas as to what could be the problem? I checked my wires and they're as you said.

Comment: it is a question which of the two headers is Atmega. that with 3.3 V is not ICSP. in schema it is JP2. so it is possible that the right header is the right header

Comment: I edited the answer. https://github.com/Arduinolibrary/DFRobot_Bluno_Bettle/raw/master/Bluno%20beetle%20V1.0%20layout%20ground.pdf

Comment: Yes, I am already connecting to the correct one which is on the left (ICSP2), so that doesn't seem to be the issue here. Would the orientation and order of ICSP2 be the same as your AVR or could they be different?

Comment: Maybe the issue is something in the code which I'm not doing?

Comment: the right is right. ICSP1. ICSP2 is not ICSP.

Comment: Tested with the other pins  on ICSP1. That definitely didn't work as the sketch didn't even enter setup() because "Initializing SD card..." didn't print. Thanks for your continued help.

Comment: if the board doesn't boot, reset is connected to ground. or a short is somewhere

Comment: Hi Juraj, the correct ICSP was on the right, ICSP1. However, the orientation of those pins were from left to right on the TOP: SCK, 5V, MISO; left to right on the BOTTOM: MOSI, RESET, GND. In the Wiki they had the ICSP labels 1 and 2 reversed, but correct in the text below. https://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/Bluno_Beetle_SKU:DFR0339

Comment: then they should not call it ICSP header, because you cant use an ICSP AVR programmer with it https://www.olimex.com/Products/AVR/Programmers/AVR-ISP-MK2/open-source-hardware

Comment: I thought that ICSP is just a protocol and doesn't really have anything to do with a certain AVR programmer.

Comment: programmers have a cable with 2x3 connector

Comment: lol, I'll verify your findings on my device later, but thanks for this post. Wow, their documentation is not only useless but f'd up on top of it!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm seeing with my multitester:

[image]

The cc2540 is the SMD chip on the same side as the ICSP pads. The atmega328p is on the opposite side of the PCB